Problem with using Gstreamer with Python 3 OpenCV to display and save a video in Desktop with Flir Hadron camera
I'm trying to display and save my Flir Hadron camera videos using gstreamer pipelines in Python 3 OpenCV. I have a perfectly working Gstreamer pipelines that are able to display and save videos with high resolution, but when I execute the Python 3 code to display and save, I get the following ERROR: (Cannot open camera. Existing) which in my opinion means that I have a problem in the camset line of code, but I still have no idea how to resolve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.
Gstreamer pipline (displays and save):
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! tee name=t ! 'video/x-raw, format=UYVY, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1' ! queue leaky=1 ! xvimagesink sync=false t. ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h265enc bitrate=8000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/RGB_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').mp4 -e 

I tried to change the camset line of code but with no better results also tried atoher python3 codes you'll find down below but it didn't work either:
python3 code:
import time
import cv2

# Cam properties
fps = 30.
frame_width = 640
frame_height = 480
# Create capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Set camera properties
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frame_width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, frame_height)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)

# Define the gstreamer sink
gst_str_rtp = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000"


# Check if cap is open
if cap.isOpened() is not True:
    print "Cannot open camera. Exiting."
    quit()

# Create videowriter as a SHM sink
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_str_rtp, 0, fps, (frame_width, frame_height), True)

# Loop it
while True:
    # Get the frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Check
    if ret is True:
        # Flip frame
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        # Write to SHM
        out.write(frame)
    else:
        print "Camera error."
        time.sleep(10)

cap.release()






Are you missing cv2.waitKey(0)?

no he is not, because there is no imshow.

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/i-am-not-able-to-display-and-save-a-video-from-my-flir-hadron-camera-using-gstreamer-command-in-python3-opencv/17370 -- related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78361491/i-am-not-able-to-display-and-save-a-video-from-my-flir-hadron-camera-using-gstre

Your main issue is that VideoWriter doesn't support UYVY, it only supports BGR and RGB color formats. Furthermore, you'd better use flip with BGR format, it may not give the expected result with UYVY.
You may convert the read UYVY frame into BGR with:
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY)

or use gstreamer backend with a pipeline converting into BGR.
Also set gstreamer backend for VideoWriter:
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_str_rtp, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, ... 

