I am not able to display and save a video from my Flir hadron camera using Gstreamer command in python3 Opencv
I'm trying to display and save my Flir Hadron camera videos using gstreamer pipelines in Python 3 OpenCV. I have a perfectly working Gstreamer pipelines that are able to display and save videos with high resolution, but when I execute the Python3 code to display and save, I get the following ERROR:

Cannot open camera. Existing

which in my opinion means that I have a problem in the camset line of code since it prints the message in the code
if cap.isOpened() is not True

I still have no idea how to resolve this problem.
Also another note: I do have gstreamer in my opencv. Any help would be appreciated.
Gstreamer pipeline (displays and save):
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! tee name=t ! 'video/x-raw, format=UYVY, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1' ! queue leaky=1 ! xvimagesink sync=false t. ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h265enc bitrate=8000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/RGB_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').mp4 -e 

python3 code:
import cv2

fps=30
frame_width=1920
frame_height=1080

camset='v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! queue ! nvvidconv ! appsink' 

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(camset,cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frame_width)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,frame_height)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)

if cam.isOpened() is not True:
    print("Cannot open camera. Existing.")
    quit()


gst_str = ' appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h265enc maxperf-enable=1 preset-level=4 control-rate=1 bitrate=16000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=streaming.mp4 ' 


fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H265')
out=cv2.VideoWriter(gst_str, fourcc , 30, (frame_width, frame_height), True)

while (True):
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    
    cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I tried to change the camset line of code but with no better results

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/i-am-not-able-to-display-and-save-a-video-from-my-flir-hadron-camera-using-gstreamer-command-in-python3-opencv/17370 -- related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78355003/problem-with-using-gstreamer-with-python-3-opencv-to-display-and-save-a-video-in

Some points that you may correct:

When using gstreamer backend for VideoCapture, you can get parameters from V4L2 parameters but you may not be able to set these. So better test the return value for ensuring it worked.
Not sure for your case, but nvvidconv may require at least one of its input or output to be in NVMM memory, which is not the case in your pipeline.
As for VideoCapture, you would specify the backend for the VideoWriter.
When using gstreamer backend for writer, the 4CC code would 0 (RAW).
When using gstreamer backend for writer, only RGB and BGR color formats are supported. So try using BGR (most opencv algorithms are available for this format). Note you would have to push BGR frames into writer, so you would convert UYVY into BGR in the capture pipeline.

So you may try this corrected version:
import cv2

# Check for gstreamer support from opencv build running in your python version
import re
print('GStreamer support: %s' % re.search(r'GStreamer\:\s+(.*)', cv2.getBuildInformation()).group(1))

#fps=30
#frame_width=1920
#frame_height=1080

# For your camera case (not tested)
#camset='v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
 
# Simulated Video source
camset='videotestsrc is-live=1 ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(camset,cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if cam.isOpened() is not True:
    print("Cannot open camera. Exiting.")
    quit()
actual_width = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
actual_height = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
actual_fps = float(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS));
print('Capture opened framing %d x %d @ %f' % (actual_width,actual_height,actual_fps))


gst_writer_str = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h265enc maxperf-enable=1 preset-level=4 control-rate=1 bitrate=16000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=streaming.mp4' 
fourcc = 0 #RAW
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_writer_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fourcc, actual_fps, (actual_width, actual_height), True)
if not out.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open writer. Exiting.")
    quit()


while (True):
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
out.release()
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Thank you for your answer i appreciate it . i undretand all the points you've talked and it makes sense tome , but i've tried the code you provided and still i get the same ERROR 'Cannot open camera. Existing' . i know think it might be when i was belding my opencv with gstreamer at the last step i cheked if i had gstreamer it was YES but when i cheked python3 it was  a path /home/bin...
i don't know if it is supposed to be like that note: i've unstalled python3 before beelding opencv with gstreamer . here is the code that i executed down below , i apppreciate any advise thank you:

'''
import cv2
camset='v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(camset,cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if cam.isOpened() is not True:
print("Cannot open camera. Existing.")
quit()
actual_width=int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
actual_heigtht=int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
actual_fps=float(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS));
'''

'''print('Capture opened framing %d x %d @ %f' % (actual_width,actual_height,actual_fps))
gst_str = ' appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! videoconvert ! video/xraw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h265enc maxperf-enable=1 preset-level=4 control-rate=1 bitrate=16000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesinklocation=streaming.mp4 '
fourcc=0
out=cv2.VideoWriter(gst_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fourcc, actual_fps, (actual_width, actual_height), True)
if not out.isOpened:
print("Cannot open writer. Existing.")
quit()
'''

'''while (True):
ret,frame = cam.read()
cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
out.write(frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
'''

Check your writer pipeline, it has errors (xraw instead of x-raw, and lacks a space between filesink and location). Better start with my example, when working try changing things one by one.

Thank you for your answer i tried to change step by step but then i figured that the problem is not the code is that i was working wit opencv without gstreamer i did build opencv with gstreamer in an environnement in which i can not import cv2 with python3 ,more details are provided in here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78374681/building-opencv-with-gstreamer
sorry for the late feedback i was really just trying to get this working thank you for your help i appreciate it

Hello, i've just got to execute the code you provided me after successfuly  building opencv with gstreamer ,the code you provided works but i got a warning that gstreamer cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1, after i change  to this camset='v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1' .The streaming is moving in slowmotion it moves very slow and the saved video was accelerated .do youhave any ideas why? thank you in advance

The warning from gstreamer backend in opencv about duration and position is common and could be safely ignored for a live source. As it now works, you may set this topic as solved if you think it is, so that next users coming here will know that this case was solved without having to read all the comments. For the performance issue, I've tried to help in your new topic.

i used the code suggested by  SEB and it worked perfectly ,and to be able to save and display from my camera i've modified the following :
import cv2

# For your camera case (not tested)
camset='v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
 

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(camset,cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if cam.isOpened() is not True:
    print("Cannot open camera. Exiting.")
    quit()
actual_width = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
actual_height = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
actual_fps = float(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS));
print('Capture opened framing %d x %d @ %f' % (actual_width,actual_height,actual_fps))


gst_writer_str = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h265enc maxperf-enable=1 preset-level=4 control-rate=1 bitrate=16000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=streaming.mp4' 
fourcc = 0 #RAW
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_writer_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fourcc, actual_fps, (actual_width, actual_height), True)
if not out.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open writer. Exiting.")
    quit()


while (True):
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
out.release()
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

